# Return an image's dimensions

Tags: python, image

How do I get the height and width (in pixels) of an image that's been imported in Blender?

`bpy.data.images['myImage'].???`

Comment: Suggest use the python console to figure out such properties: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html

Comment: thanks. I used it as well as the tab function and thought size may be it but didn't find how to return the x and y values from it. @aliasguru's answer clear it out for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `size` property to get the X and Y dimensions of an image:

```
width, height = bpy.data.images['myImage'].size
# the variables width and height will now contain the pixel size
```

Comment: Thanks! How come I can't return the values without assigning them?

Comment: @ChameleonScales Well, you could. the `size` property is simply an array, you could access the values like `bpy.data.images['myImage'].size[0]` and `bpy.data.images['myImage'].size[1]`. However, I tend to find the given answer to be more Pythonic. See https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-tuple-list-unpack/ for a deeper explanation

Comment: oh, of course, where's my head